# PHP SimpleXML how do i get this value?

Tags: php, xml

How would i go around retrieving the value of `<TotalNew>` in the example file below? I am unfamiliar with simplexml. I tried to access it as following: `ItemLookupResponse->Items->Item->TotalNew` but it did not produce a result.

Anyone who can point me out how to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ItemLookupResponse  xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
<OperationRequest>
<HTTPHeaders>
  <Header Name="UserAgent" Value="ApaiIO [2.0.0-DEV]"/>
</HTTPHeaders>
<RequestId>3ba918b6-7a00-4251-b24d-be8a40cb3eb8</RequestId>
<Arguments>
  <Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value=""/>
  <Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value=""/>
  <Argument Name="Condition" Value="New"/>
  <Argument Name="ItemId" Value=""/>
  <Argument Name="Operation" Value="ItemLookup"/>
  <Argument Name="ResponseGroup" Value="OfferSummary"/>
  <Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService"/>
  <Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2015-09-08T07:39:02Z"/>
  <Argument Name="Version" Value="2011-08-01"/>
  <Argument Name="Signature" Value="eglWsk68VxzDOE8PIdQdNget9RhZvPiBZylxpgn94ns="/>
</Arguments>
<RequestProcessingTime>0.0138980000000000</RequestProcessingTime>
</OperationRequest>
<Items>
<Request>
  <IsValid>True</IsValid>
  <ItemLookupRequest>
    <Condition>New</Condition>
    <IdType>ASIN</IdType>
    <ItemId></ItemId>
    <ResponseGroup>OfferSummary</ResponseGroup>
    <VariationPage>All</VariationPage>
  </ItemLookupRequest>
</Request>
<Item>
  <ASIN></ASIN>
  <ParentASIN></ParentASIN>
  <OfferSummary>
    <LowestNewPrice>
      <Amount>699</Amount>
      <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      <FormattedPrice>$6.99</FormattedPrice>
    </LowestNewPrice>
    <LowestUsedPrice>
      <Amount>599</Amount>
      <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      <FormattedPrice>$5.99</FormattedPrice>
    </LowestUsedPrice>
    <TotalNew>3</TotalNew>
    <TotalUsed>1</TotalUsed>
    <TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible>
    <TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished>
  </OfferSummary>
</Item>
```

Comment: Most likely you've overseen the *OfferSummary* from you accepting the given answer, but you might have an easier live with taking a look into xpath to query for the elements you're looking for as it's more flexible: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-6023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML has an error.  Add the following to the end of your XML..

```
    </Items>
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

Then you can use the following..  ..bearing in mind that there may be multiple `<item>` elements inside `<items>`, so you will have to loop through them.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

foreach ($xml->Items as $item){

    echo $item->Item->OfferSummary->TotalNew->__toString();

}
```

If you can guarantee that there will only ever be one `<Item>` inside `<Items>`, or you just want to target the first `<Item>`, you could achieve this without a loop, by targeting the first value of the `<Items>` array using `Item[0]`.

```
echo $xml->Items->Item[0]->OfferSummary->TotalNew->__toString();
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Thanks for pointing out the error in the xml as well

Comment: With `echo` you don't need to explicitly use `->__toString()` method, in string context, it will be converted to string automatically (that is for what that magic method is for). And `Items->Item->OfferSummary` will always relate to the first `Item` - whether there is one or whether there are more than one. Only in case if there is none, `->OfferSummary` will be `null`, but otherwise it will represent the first OfferSummary child-element of the first Item child-element of the (again first) Items child-element of the document element (see, you used that already for *Items*). Just saying.